# AWS Route53 - How to route rest requests to appropriate apigateway in different regions based on url endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have API gateway configured  in us-east-1 and us-west-1 to serve rest service requests. Also,i have a Route53 which is on failover policy. Only us-east-1 is primary, it will be failed over to us-west-1 only when health check failed in us-east-1. As i'm planning to make things active-active, i need to route the read calls to both the regions, however write calls to only us-east-1 as primary. Is it possible to achieve this requirement?  Can i route the traffic of my rest service requests based on url parameters.

Comment: Not sure you can do this with but you could do this with CloudFront and Lambda@Edge in front of your API gateway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to achieve this requirement?

No. Route53 does not participate in your API's read or write operations. It does not differentiate between them, thus it can't "direct" read operations different that write operations.